# Vim map failed unless reload .vimrc

Tags: vim

I want to do the following maps in my .vimrc.local

```

```
inoremap <C-H> <Left>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>

inoremap <C-J> <Down>
inoremap <C-K> <Up>
inoremap <C-L> <Right>
```

```

When I restart my vim, the fist two mapping failed, and the last three commands succeeded. However, when I `source ~/.vimrc.local`, then all the five mapping methods are OK. That means, I need to load my .vimrc.local myself.

I've already write `source ~/.vimrc.local` in my .vimrc . And if I source ~/.vimrc rather than .vimrc.local, it works as well.

What's wrong with my mapping? Is there any conflict? I searched in my .vimrc and .vimrc.local, but didn't find conflicts.

I'm using OS X 10.9 and MacVim Snapshot 71, and the main .vimrc from spf13. There are my [.vimrc](https://gist.github.com/guori12321/11216197#file-gistfile1-txt) and [.vimrc.local](https://gist.github.com/guori12321/11216257).

How can I do the mapping without manually reload .vimrc?

Thanks!

Comment: not familiar with mac, but could that be that the vim was started by other user (some default user?), who doesn't have that local file under `~`?  you can add some thing in your local file, when vim starts, check if it was really sourced. Or try put absolute path to your vimrc.local file in vimrc.... and a little advice, do NOT use any vim "distribution"

Comment: Conflicts? That's more than probable given the pointless complexity added by SPF13. Try those mappings without that crappy distribution first.

Comment: First, check `:scriptnames` and make sure that `.vimrc` and `.vimrc.local` are being sourced.  Probably they are, and your vimrc file should be one of the first files listed.  Next, try `:verbose imap <C-H>` and `:verbose map <C-H>`.  Does that tell you anything useful?

Comment: Do you, perchance, have any mappings for `<BS>` (Backspace)? Many times Vim cannot distinguish between the two, and the mappings will collide.

Comment: @benjifisher thanks, `:verbose` showed the conflict.  Just curious though, `:scriptnames` showed my .vimrc being sourced first, and I thought `inoremap` was supposed to prevent a setting getting overridden.  I don't understand why a Plugin would override it.  I am using Vundle, and I tried the `:noremap` both before and after  my Vundle settings.

Comment: Are you the OP?  If you were able to diagnose the problem, then please answer the question and mark it as solved.As for `:inoremap`, I think you are mistaken.  Nothing prevents one script from overriding another script's mappings, whether Normal or Input modes, "nore" or not.  The "nore" versions of the `:map` commands simply mean that, when the map is triggered, other mapping commands are not triggered.  `:help :inoremap` or `:help 40.1` and search for "nore".